# Creating a multiple page pdf file with macros in excel

Tags: excel, pdf

Trying to solve this i run into this code:

```
*ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="*****", _
openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False, From:=1, To:=5*
```

My problem is that i have created a loop in order to update multiple times one sheet. Aparently the above code works for a "fixed" Sheet and export it in a pdf file up to 5 pages. So it does not work if i want to save each updated Sheet into a page of one pdf file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Would help to show the rest of your code

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. I managed to solve it. Thank you though.